# C++ template macro shortcut

Tags: c++, templates, macros

Often when working with templates, you end up with something like:

```
template <T>
class the_class
{
public:
   // types
   typedef T value_type;
   typedef const value_type const_value_type;

   typedef value_type& reference;
   typedef const_value_type& const_reference;

   typedef value_type* pointer;
   typedef const_value_type* const_pointer;

   ...
};
```

This is lot's of the same stuff, though, copied to lots of different templated classes. Is it worthwhile to create something like:

```
// template_types.h

#define TEMPLATE_TYPES(T) \
       typedef T value_type; \
       typedef const value_type const_value_type; \
       typedef value_type& reference; \
       typedef const_value_type& const_reference; \
       typedef value_type* pointer; \
       typedef const_value_type* const_pointer;
```

So my class just becomes:

```
#include "template_types.h"

template <typename T>
class the_class
{
public:
   TEMPLATE_TYPES(T)
   ...
};
```

This seems cleaner, and avoids duplication when I make other template classes. Is this a good thing? Or should I avoid this and just copy-paste typedefs?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Sure, what you're doing would work, but it's kind of old-school. Have you tried to put that stuff into another template class that you could derive from?

```
template <typename T>
class template_defs
{
public:
   // types
   typedef T value_type;
   typedef const value_type const_value_type;
   typedef value_type& reference;
   typedef const_value_type& const_reference;
   typedef value_type* pointer;
   typedef const_value_type* const_pointer;
};

template <typename T>
class the_class : public template_defs<T>
...
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't even think of that.

Comment: +1 This is also the reason why to inherit functors from unary and binary function. I actually had a related question, how one would **use** those typedefs in the_class (supposing they are obtained through some metaprogramming voodoo) but from http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates.html#faq-35.18 it appears there's no *meaningful* way...

Comment: -1 from me.  I disagree with this solution due to the "names not found in a dependent base class" issue.  Every reference to to one of these members has to be qualified as follows:   "typename template_defs<T>::".  For example if you want to refer to "const_reference", you'd have to say "typename template_defs<T>::const_reference" which isn't really much better.  A solution that mixes the macro version with the template however, might be OK.

Comment: Actually, my downvote won't be registered.  I previously voted followed by undo, and apparently that still starts the "vote locking timer" so I am unable to re-cast my vote.  I must admit that there are some features of the SO site that really confuse me, and in case anybody is interested this /is/ by design:  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18360/vote-too-old-to-be-changed-but-i-havent-voted

Comment: I suppose it would be good to be aware of both techniques. Personally I don't see a reason why I should type `const_reference` instead of just `const T&`. Those typedefs are not vital for the implementation of the_class, rather they are useful for the user, providing some simple metaprogramming capabilities.